# How to set default response format in spring-mvc using 'Content Negotiation Manager' when invalid format is given?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, response, content-negotiation

> I wanted to get response from spring-mvc-controller either in **json or xml format** depending on the **parameter - 'format'** in the **URL**. I am able to achieve this using **ContentNegotiation** as shown in below code.
>
> The only problem is if I give an **invalid value in the parameter 'format'** I am getting error response
>   **(HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable).**
>
> How to set this to **default json even when input is invalid.**
>
> Below is the configuration:

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class RespConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer
        .favorPathExtension(false)
        .favorParameter(true)
        .parameterName("format")
        .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
        .useJaf(false)
        .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .mediaType("xm", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

> **The response of the above configuration is as below :**
>
> **for url http://localhost:8080/SpringApi?format=xml**  ::  xml response (as configured)
>
> **for url http://localhost:8080/SpringApi?format=json** ::  json response (as configured)
>
> **for url http://localhost:8080/SpringApi**             ::  json response by default (as configured)
>
> **for url http://localhost:8080/SpringApi?format=abc**  :: **(HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable).**

[image: Screenshot the error in the browser :]